# Trouble with Lists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method setTopping(String topping) which takes a String as a parameter. Adds the String to a List, and depending what the String is, sets a value. eg salami 0.6, fungi 0.5 etc.

Now I have a List of Strings. It might contain 1, 2, 3 or 4 Strings. I want to add, in turn, the first String to the chooseTopping() method, then the second string, then, if there is one, the 3rd string.

However after adding 3 toppings, I got the output:

```
  [0.6]
  [salami]
  [0.6, 0.7]
  [salami, bacon]
  [0.6, 0.7, 0.5]
  [salami, bacon, fungi]
```

When I was expecting:

```
  [0.6, 0.7, 0.5]
  [salami, bacon, fungi]
```

What would be the best way to iterate through a list of an unknown quantity of Strings, and add them one by one to a method which takes Strings as a parameter?

Many Thanks

EDIT
the print statements were in the for loop, thats why the output was multiplied

Comment: Thats the best way. Maybe your setTopping is not implemented as you expect it is.

Comment: I've edited in my setTopping method incase#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would really like to help you, but we need a little bit more context. Can you provide the full method that contains this for loop?

Comment: How did you populate The List toppings?

Comment: what is actually wrong with the output?!

Comment: The output is like, [0.6]
  [pepperoni]
  [0.6, 0.7]
  [pepperoni, bacon]
  [0.6, 0.7, 0.5]
  [pepperoni, bacon, fungi]

Comment: Its printing out pepperoni 3 times, bacon 2 times

Comment: which method is printing that?

Comment: sorry, I worked it out myself, I put the print statements in the for loop.. So it printed the output 2-3-4 times. Pretty stupid

Comment: Thats what I wrote in my answer, but I'm glad that you solved it on your own :)

Comment: I guess it is because it must be "funghi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these prints after the for:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < toppings.size() ; i++){ 
    t.setTopping( toppings.get(i)  );
    }
    System.out.println( t.getCost() );
    System.out.println( t.getTopping() );
    System.out.println( b.getBase() );
```

I think that these getcost and gettopping will always print the full list, but you want to print only 1 time at the end.